# Why $F_{|X\times {\{t}\}}$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ is homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

The following text is the definition and an example for isotopy:

[image]

I don't understand why $F_{|X\times {\{t}\}}$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ is homeomorphism. According to the definition of homeomorphism, one must show that $F_{|X\times {\{t}\}}$ and it's inverse is continuous, but I have no idea how to that. Is continuity must be shown on length of the vector x?
Please help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fixed $t$ it should be clear that $F|_{X \times \{t\}}$ is continuous: for example when $t=0.5$, the function is $x \mapsto 1.5 x$.

The inverse of $F|_{X \times \{t\}}$ is $x/(t+1)$, which is also clearly continuous. (Remember, $t$ is fixed!)

Comment: the thing that I don't understand is that $x$ is a vector not a single variable, how $x↦1.5x$ is to be continuous when $x$ is a vector?

Comment: $x:=(x_1,x_2)$, and $1.5x:= (1.5x_1,1.5x_2)$.